# Use a "0" in a PHP JSON request

Tags: php, html, json, parsing

I'm trying to create a PHP page that pulls data from Forecast.io's API. For the daily view, they give the days up as numbers. I want info from today, so the number is a "0." My code looks like this:

```
<?php

echo '<h4>', round(($data->daily->data->0->apparentTemperatureMax)*5/9) , '&deg;F</h4>';
echo '<h2>', round(($data->currently->apparentTemperature)*5/9) , '&deg;F</h2>'; 
echo '<h4>', round(($data->daily->data->0->apparentTemperatureMin)*5/9) , '&deg;F</h4>'; ?>`
```

Where it states the Min and Max temperature, the "0" is a part of the JSON format that forecast.io uses. However, PHP throws an error whenever I try this. The error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\wamp64\www\PHP Weather Widget\index.php on line 35
```

Is there any way to use the zero, or do I need to parse the data using another method to avoid this?

A sample file of the JSON data returned:https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast
can be entered into this site: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to view a tree view  of the data returned. You can see the format by going to "daily->data."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data` is an array, not an object.

Comment: `0` is an index, use `data[0]` instead

Comment: Pleased to say that the data[0] method worked

Comment: My answer below explains that! Glad to know it helped.

Comment: always remember `[....]` is parsed as array and `{.....}` is parsed as object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `$data->daily->data->0->apparentTemperatureMax` try doing `$data['daily']['data'][0]['apparentTemperatureMax']`. $data is an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $data = json_encode($yourResponse, true), so you can use the data as a array. In your case, the access will be something like $data['daily']['data'][0]['apparentTemperatureMax']